# How would I isolate or just store the second element in a for loop inside a batch file?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, indexing

I'm using a loop inside a Windows batch file to return PID numbers and I only want to use the second PID number. How do I set the second element, the second PID number as a variable or just use it in a command in the loop instead of `echo`?

The code..

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /FO CSV ^| findstr /I cmd.exe') do (
    echo PID:%%a
)
```

I tried indexing the element like this `PID:%%a[1]`. It didn't work.

Comment: Assuming you want the second instance of `CMD.exe`, just use the `FOR` commands `SKIP=` option.  Then break out of the `FOR`  command with a `GOTO` command.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /FO CSV ^| findstr /I cmd.exe ^| findstr /N "^" ^| findstr /B "2:"') do echo PID:%%a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want deal like this code ?

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /FO CSV ^| findstr /I cmd.exe') do (
    set /A count+=1
    Set "PID[!count!]=%%~a"
)

@For /L %%i in (1,1,%count%) do echo PID[%%i] = !PID[%%i]!
echo( I want this PID = !PID[2]!
pause
```